# Parsing xml childnodes in python

Tags: python, xml

I have got this xml file :

```
 <ItemArray>
    <Item>
      <GiftIcon>0</GiftIcon>
      <HitCounter>NoHitCounter</HitCounter>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TimeLeft>P9DT17H35M6S</TimeLeft>
      <Title>Table</Title>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <GiftIcon>0</GiftIcon>
      <HitCounter>NoHitCounter</HitCounter>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TimeLeft>PT0S</TimeLeft>
      <Title>Chair</Title>
    </Item>
  </ItemArray>
```

I would like to return "Title" if "TimeLeft" is not "PT0S" :

So far I have got this :

```
itemList = response.getElementsByTagName('Item')
children = itemList[0].childNodes
for child in children :
  if child.tagName == "TimeLeft":
    if child.childNodes[0].nodeValue == "PT0S": 
       print "ping"
```

But I don't know how to get back to the "Title" value from there, what would be a more elegant way to return a childnode's value depending if an other childnode is true or false ?

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that I use xml.dom.minidom , I will give xpath a shot .

Comment: @Fingertwist -- if you need to do more of this, do yourself a favour and use lxml

Answer (score 4):

use `xpath`:

`doc.xpath('.//item[timeleft/text()!="PT0S"]/title/text()'`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Python's ElementTree API and simple list comprehension:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('your_xml_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

titles = [item.find('Title').text for item in root.findall('Item') if item.find('TimeLeft').text != 'PT0S']
```

`titles` will be a list of titles of items for which `TimeLeft` is not `PT0S`. This is easier to read than an XPath-based solution (if you're not familiar with XPath) in my opinion.